# In Chrome the related questions numbers overlap comments

Tags: bug, design, related-questions

I do not have the issue on the same box in IE8 nor in FX22/FX23

My specs:

- XP Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m (But still the case in Chrome 32)
- Large system fonts (Is that the reason?)
- 2560x1440 resolution
- Zoom: 100%, issue does not go away if I zoom out
- Example page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097060/html-not-display-watermark-image-in-each-page-print

Chrome 28 side by side with FX23

[image]

I can right now only reproduce it when I click *show more comments*

In the example below, the related questions behave nicely, but when I click show more comments, all comments reflow and dip under the related questions

**BEFORE**
[image]
**AFTER**
[image]

Comment: "Large system fonts" - yes, most likely the issue here.

Comment: @Vigbyor No, that's broken for me, too. It's unrelated to large fonts, it's a markdown problem.

Comment: The strange thing is that sometimes the page reflows - so for example @Vigbyor s link works for me right now if I click

Comment: Reproduced by forcing 16px font size via Chrome dev tool: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BaGli.png so yes, that's surely the large system fonts you chose.

Comment: I can zoom without any change. If it is bad it is bad, if it is good it stays good. I doubt a post from 2009 is relevant with the changes the site has made since. For example I recently lost margins on all my idevices. ALso I have almost as much whitespace on both sides of the actual content as the content is wide. the answers to the duplicate post did not answer my issue either

Comment: I get that ALL the time, including right now as I comment.

Comment: @LanceRoberts and what are your system fonts set to?

Comment: On this machine in Firefox: Times New Roman, 20.  Windows uses a lot of Segue UI, 10 with settings of 125%.

Comment: I do not have the issue on the same box in IE8 nor in FX22

Comment: Still the case in Feb 2014

Answer (score 1):

Here are my screenshots from Firefox 25.0.1, the overlap happens when I hit the more comment link

> add / show 3 more comments

Without overlap:

[image: Without Overlap]

With overlap:

[image: With Overlap]

Default Font: Times New Roman, 20
Windows 7 Display Settings: 2560x1440, Medium(125%) magnification
(Note: Those are for my home computer, but I get the same thing at work, will update when I get back there to get the numbers)

Comment: I have this still and am now on Chrome 32